# How can I have a server stream a video with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

My current use case is that I'm trying to mock a system that uses WebRTC for live video streaming (for a robot). This way, I don't have to be connected to the robot to develop the client.

My issue as of now is that I have no idea how to stream a video using WebRTC to connected peers. I've seen many examples of how to do this from client to client using a signaling server, but other than directly sending the video buffer using socket.io, I haven't seen an example of server -> client WebRTC streaming.

I'm planning to use Node.JS for mocking the video stream as I've been using it for the rest of the robot's systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really isn't that different though client to client or server to client. You want to stream/broadcast a video to all the connected peers. Think of your server will be a client in the setup.

You can also use a WebRTC solution like [Janus](http://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) [Repo](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) it is a simple gateway and completely open source. Refer to - [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org) & [Dev API's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) for more info.

If you find latency issues after peers have increased in number you can check - [Mesh](https://bloggeek.me/webrtcglossary/mesh/), [Routing](http://webrtcglossary.com/routing/), [Multi peer architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2N0d6CKrbk&t=0s) for some solutions for it.

Hope it helps.